# Access store procedure value from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to run a stored procedure from my MVC controller and get a count value from SQL database server. Please check controller code below. There I have called my procedure- "CountSearchedUserItems" but problem is I am not getting any output in debug.

I have attached picture of debug on bottom on question, please check.

How can I fix my controller to run that procedure and get that simple `int` value?

Controller:

```
using (var ctx = new db_demoEntities()){
    var foo = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<db_demoEntities>("CountSearchedUserItems");
}
```

Store Procedure code:

```
--CREATE PROCEDURE CountSearchedUserItems
--AS
--Begin
--select Count(*) from SearchedUserItems
--End

CountSearchedUserItems //now i can call this procedure successfully from mssql managment
```

debug pic:
[image: debug pic]

ms sql management test:
[image: ms sql management test]

Comment: what is in the `foo` holded ?

Comment: "ms sql management test" see this pic. this will hold just a int value

Comment: http://ibb.co/kPhCpx see this picture. it has error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method expects the desired return type in the generic argument.

if you expect an `int` count then use `int` as generic argument parameter

```
int foo = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>("EXEC CountSearchedUserItems").First();
```

As the result returned is a collection you will need to enumerate it to get the value.